# Android - Changing tabs and listview items repeats

Tags: android, tabs, repeat

I work to an application in android and I had one situation that I can't figure out what is happening. The app is with 3 tabs, created with Fragments and TabHost and every tab have a list of articles with specific content.

I have a listview inside the last tab. The listview is created with listAdapter and is populated from a drupal view. Everything works perfect, but when I change tab and come back to the initial tab, items of listview repeats.

The code of tab content is:

```
   httpconnect httpcon = new httpconnect();   
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          if (container == null) { 
             return null;
          } 
             View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recomandate, container, false);   
             list=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list); 
             infoGet();  
             return v;  
    }


    public void infoGet() { 
            try {   
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(httpcon.connectareHttp(url));  

           for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) { 
               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);             

                String id; 
                   id = json.getString("nid"); 
                    map.put(KEY_ID, id);  

                 String articleTitle; 
                  articleTitle= json.getString("title"); 
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, articleTitle);

                  String content; 
                    content= json.getString("body"); 
                      map.put(KEY_BODY, content);

                   String img; 
                     img = json.getString("field_image"); 
                       map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, img); 

                  articleList.add(map);  
           }

                adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), articleList);  
                  list.setAdapter(adapter);  

        }   catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
                    } 

    }
```

How can I make not to repeate items from listview when I change between tabs?

Thanks in advance for help!

Regards, Cosso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your answer is here:

```
         articleList.add(map);
```

you keep re-adding every time the items.

When you call `.replace()` in a FragmentTransaction, you're not re instantiating the fragment object but the FragmentManger is asking the fragment to `createView()` every time to make sure it will fit and layout properly on the ViewGroup.